# Collecting custom end user feedback for Mobile Apps?

Tags: iphone, android, feedback

I have a few iphone and andriod apps and would like to collect better and more targeted user feedback for them. The feedback from the App stores is pretty generic and doesn't add much value at most times.

Any framework or website that I could use to help here? Kind of like Get Satisfaction for Mobile Apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Promobe](http://www.promobe.com).  They are a service for mobile app developers that provides a rich user feedback mechanism - you can define custom feedback forms for each of your apps, track that feedback, publish promotion codes, etc.

It's a new service that just went into beta but looks pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing for Android, you can take a look on [LetThemVote](http://www.letthemvote.com).
It's a free feedback collector service which provides an API+Client UI.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of LTV